# Oracle SQL with parameters not working?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, dynamic-sql

I'm familiar with SQL Server but new to Oracle. I'm working on doing a bulk insert or update using the Array technique I've found in some examples. However, I must be doing this incorrect because I'm getting errors about "invalid table.column". I have a feeling it has to do with the way I'm trying to assign parameter names in the in-line SQL and command parameters. In the example I've seen they use numeric values for the parameters like ":1, :2, :3" but if possible I would like to use ":paramtername1, :parametername2, :parametername3".

Here is what I'm doing

```
sbQuery.Append("update SAP_EMPLOYEE set ");
sbQuery.Append(" EMP_ID = :p_EmployeeId, EVENT_FROM_DT = :p_EventFromDate, EVENT_TYP = :p_EventType, EVENT_RSN = :p_EventRsn,");
sbQuery.Append(" where Emp = :p_Employee");
```

Then I create arrays to add the values to

```
string[] arrEmployee = new string[listEmployee.Count];
string[] arrEmployeeId = new string[listEmployee.Count];
DateTime[] arrEventFromDt = new DateTime[listEmployee.Count];
string[] arrEventTyp = new string[listEmployee.Count];
string[] arrEventRsn = new string[listEmployee.Count];
```

Populate the arrays

```
int i = 0;
foreach (SAP_EMPLOYEE item in listEmployee)
{
    arrEmployee[i] = item.EMP;
    arrEmployeeId[i] = item.EMP_ID;
    if(item.EVENT_FROM_DT.HasValue)
    {
        arrEventFromDt[i] = item.EVENT_FROM_DT.Value;
    }
    arrEventTyp[i] = item.EVENT_TYP;
    arrEventRsn[i] = item.EVENT_RSN;

    i++;
}
```

Then call the connection, cmd, query

```
OracleConnection objConnection = new OracleConnection(connString);
using (objConnection)
{
    objConnection.Open();

    //create Oracle parameters and pass arrays of data
    OracleParameter p_Employee = new OracleParameter();
    p_Employee.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
    p_Employee.Value = arrEmployee;

    OracleParameter p_EmployeeId = new OracleParameter();
    p_EmployeeId.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
    p_EmployeeId.Value = arrEmployeeId;

    OracleParameter p_EventFromDate = new OracleParameter();
    p_EventFromDate.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Date;
    p_EventFromDate.Value = arrEventFromDt;

    OracleParameter p_EventType = new OracleParameter();
    p_EventType.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Char;
    p_EventType.Value = arrEventTyp;

    OracleParameter p_EventRsn = new OracleParameter();
    p_EventType.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Char;
    p_EventType.Value = arrEventRsn;


    OracleCommand objCmd = objConnection.CreateCommand();
    objCmd.CommandText = sbQuery.ToString();
    objCmd.ArrayBindCount = arrEmployee.Length;

    objCmd.Parameters.Add(p_Employee);
    objCmd.Parameters.Add(p_EmployeeId);
    objCmd.Parameters.Add(p_EventFromDate);
    objCmd.Parameters.Add(p_EventType);
    objCmd.Parameters.Add(p_EventRsn);

    objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have an extra comma at the end of the updated columns : ...EVENT_RSN = :p_EventRsn,

Comment: Thanks for looking but that's just because I trimmed out a bunch of the query. There are about 30 fields it's working with but for simplicity I only pulled code for small set.

Comment: Did you check that the schema you are connecting in Oracle DB has the appropriate grant on the specified table to do the update and that the table that you specified is in the connecting schema  ?

Comment: Not sure exactly what I did to fix it but I went back and commented out most of the code and did just an insert on two fields. That worked so I added two more and so on until all the fields were added. I've now got it to work all the way down to dealing with the last field which is a date issue. Oracle dates and I don't get along very well but I'll have to post a separate question if I don't figure it out soon.